# move files within source folder to destination folder without deleting source folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, unix, amazon-s3

I am trying to move sub folders from one directory of a S3 bucket to another directory in the same bucket. After moving files within the sub folder, the main directory gets deleted, which must not happen for me.

```
aws s3 mv s3://Bucket-Name/Input-List/$i/  s3://Bucket-Name/Input-List-Archive/$i/   --recursive

COLLECTION_LIST=(A B C D E F)
for i in ${COLLECTION_LIST[@]}
do

if [ $i == "A" -o $i == "B" ]
        then
                aws s3 mv s3://Bucket-Name/Input-List/$i/  s3://Bucket-Name/Input-List-Archive/$i/   --recursive
    else
                aws s3 mv s3://Bucket-Name/Input-List/Others/$i/  s3://Bucket-Name/Input-List-Archive/Others/$i/  --recursive
```

Here all files within `Input-List` must be moved to `Input-List-Archive` without `Input-List` directory being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a script to copy the files recursively from sub folders and deleting those files from sub folder instead of using mv command?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please note that directories/folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3.

For example, I could run this command:

```
aws s3 cp foo.txt s3://my-bucket/folder1/folder2/foo.txt
```

This will work successfully, even if `folder1` and `folder2` do not exist.

The Amazon S3 management console will make those folders 'appear', but they do not actually exist.

If I then ran:

```
aws s3 rm s3://my-bucket/folder1/folder2/foo.txt
```

then the object would be deleted and the folders would 'disappear' (because they never actually existed).

Sometimes, however, people want a folder to appear. When a folder is created in the management console, a **zero-length object is created** with the Key (filename) set to the name of the folder. This will force an empty 'folder' to appear, but it is not actually a folder.

When listing objects in S3, API calls can return a **common prefix** which is similar in concept to a folder, but it is really just the "path portion" of a filename.

It is also worth mentioning that **there is no "move" command in Amazon S3**. Instead, when using the `aws s3 mv` command, the AWS CLI copies the object to a new object and then deletes the original object. This makes the object look like it was moved, but it actually was copied and deleted.

So, your options are:

- Don't worry about folders. Just pretend they exist. They do not serve any purpose. *OR*
- Create a new folder after the move. *OR*
- Write your own program to Copy & Delete the objects without deleting the folder.

In fact, it is quite possible that the folder never existed in the first place (that is, there was no zero-length file with a Key matching the name of the folder), so it was never actually deleted. It's just that there was nothing to cause S3 to make the folder 'appear' to be there.

Comment: found the solution, 
aws s3api put-object --bucket bucket_name --key folder/to/create
solved the problem

the idea is to create the structure first and then push the files, that way the directory structure remains though empty